# ServiceStack.Redis throws PlatformNotSupported Exception from unity exported .apk file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, redis, servicestack.redis

I am using ServiceStack. Redis to access my remote Redis Server. It doesn't throw any exceptions when I run it on my PC(Unity Android Environment). After I export `.apk` file from Unity and run the program on my android phone, it throws PlatformNotSupported exception. Is that because I don't include some `.dll` files? Or is ServiceStack. Redis not able to run on the mobile devices? I am a newbie to unity and servicestack.redis. Does anyone have idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you import ServiceStack.Redis  in unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception is because ServiceStack.Redis is using an API that's not supported on Android which throws a `PlatformNotSupported` at runtime when called.

Mobile devices like iOS/Android isn't a tested or supported platform for ServiceStack.Redis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any Redis c# client I can use on mobile devices? Or is there any other key-value stores that is more suitable for mobile apps?

Comment: @QinzhuXu no I don’t sorry